# Webcomic Identification: couch potatoes with super powers

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, powers

Countless years ago I read a web comic, I think it was on Keenspace.

The two main characters were couch potatoes. It starts out with them sitting at home on their couch then getting sucked into their TV, and they end up in some fantasy world and gain Dragonball-like super powers (flying, teleportation, kamehameha-lasers?). They also used swords.

I think the main character was called Nick. He had a blue shirt and red shoes (the comic was done in color). At some point he lost his memory, almost drowns in a river and gets harpooned by an elf girl who then says "sorry I thought you were a big-ass fish". I think there were a lot of girls in this story, collected in a harem-esque fashion.

One of the monsters they fought looked like Dragonball's Piccolo (green alien with either pointy ears or antenna), it was immortal, and they beat it by beheading it and burying the (still living) head.

That's about all I remember. Does it ring any bells and does it still exist somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found it through the wayback machine: It was called ["Jamie and Nick"](http://www.jamieandnick.com/) and dates back to 2001.

> Jamie and Nick, two guy like people, have been pulled into anouther [sic] world! Can they survive? What's with the carrots? Is the shadowy stranger friend or foe? Who is this "Food Devil?" Poorly written and badly drawn, the awesome saga starts here!